# Using ng-disabled inside of an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a radio input that contains an ng-repeat that has ng-disabled which fires a function that has an if else if block inside of it. If one of the conditions are met a boolean is returned. My problem is that I only want certain radios disabled if the condition their condition is met. Currently if the conditions is met the boolean will be set for all of the items in the array. How do I run functions for ng-disabled inside of ng-repeat and satisfy conditions on a per item basis?

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, add code :)

Comment: If, for example, your `ng-repeat` is over `item in items`, you would just pass `item` into the `ng-disabled` function, and return the boolean value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass **item** or repeat **$index** to your checker function for differentiation, like this:

```
<input ng-repeat="item in yourItems" type="radio" ng-disabled="yourChecker($index, item)">
```

And in controller js:

```
$scope.yourChecker = function(index, item){
    if(index==x){
       // TODO: return state here
    }

    // Or check item property

    if(item.x){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" ng-repeat="element in array track by $index" ng-disabled="isDisabled(element)">{{element}}</input>
</form>
```

Define `isDisabled` in your scope, and use the properties of any given `element` to return a boolean. If you want to do it based on the index, you can pass `$index` to the function as well.